# How to find the location of the Null Pointer Error from LogCat - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I can't seem to locate where the npe is coming from; the Null Point exception comes in run time but does not disrupt or crash the app, I went through a few questions here but there was no 'caused by' statement in the trace

the part with the error:

```
2021-09-13 12:00:00 com.example.app W/com.example.ap: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2021-09-13 12:00:00 com.example.app E/Main: error java.lang.NullPointerException
2021-09-13 12:00:00 com.example.app D/ScrollView: initGoToTop
```

that's all trace related to the error; i checked above and below but there wasn't any indication of which line/file it is coming from,

thank you

Comment: I suspect there might be a try/catch in the `Main` class. That only prints out the message, not the stack trace. 
Can you share the code of the `Main` class?

Comment: Looks like you have a catch block that logs the NPE and otherwise swallows it.

Comment: try to run program in debug mode with breakpoints and you will be able to catch the NPE (provided you set breakpoints at right places)